# Why element is hiding but doesn't load content into iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Help is required :) I've piece of the code, like this:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hexagons.css">
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//            function disp(){
//                document.getElementById('hexGrid').style.display = 'none';
//            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
   <iframe name="display" id="display_template"></iframe>

    <ul id="hexGrid">
        <?php
        foreach ($dirs as $link) {
            if ($link != 'assets') {
            echo '
            <li class="hex">
                <div class="hexIn">
                    <a class="hexLink" href="'.$linkArray[$link].'" onclick="disp(); return false;" target="display" >
                        <img src="assets/dir.png" alt="'.$link.'" />
                        <h1>' . $link . '</h1>
                        <p>Redirect to template</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            ';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    </body>
```

I wanted to achieve that on onClick at link, #hexGrid will change display style to none and in the same time to iframe will be loaded some content.

When JS is commented, on click, iframe is loading selected content correctly, but while JS is active it is simply making hidden #hexGrid without loading content into iframe.

Any idea what went wrong ? :)

Comment: Ignore you have shown the JS ...

Comment: So you are saying that the iframe doesnt load when you comment out the JS?

Comment: yes, and i don't have an idea why it works like that

Comment: So it's loading a blank page or your getting a console error?

Comment: it stays at the same page, just hide that #hexGrid. Console says that, there is a problem with loading favicon.ico. Nothing else.

Comment: solution found there should be `onclick="disp(); return true;"` instead `onclick="disp(); return false;"`

Comment: Oh right. Post the answer to help other people who have the same problem in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found there should be onclick="disp(); return true;" instead onclick="disp(); return false;"